# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I can't displayed array's state in order to push an object in it.
The CreateCards components return the good information in addCart function.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        cards: []
    }
}


addCart(title, qte){
    console.log(title);
    console.log(qte);
    console.log(this.state.cards);
    //let array = this.state.cards;
    //array.push({title: title, qte: qte});
}

render(){
    console.log(this.state.string);
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>Panier</h2>

            </div>
            {
                data.map((bike, index)=>{
                    return (
                        <CreateCards key={index} title={bike.title} img={bike.img} price={bike.price} addCart={this.addCart}/>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You forgot to bind `addCart` to the component. Add `this.addCart  = this.addCart.bind(this)` in the constructor and it should work.

Comment: `data.map` makes no sense to me as you have not declared the variable `data` anywhere in this code. Is that a global variable ?

Comment: data is import at the beginning of my file (import data from 'data.js')

Answer (score 0):

Your addCart function should be like

```
addCart(title, qte){
   console.log(title);
   console.log(qte);
   const array = this.state.cards.concat({title: title, qte: qte})
   this.setState({cards: array})
}
```

Push method mutates the state, so use concat instead of it. It returns a new array.

Answer (score -2):

You should also use 

`const newCards = this.state.cards.push({title: title, qte: qte});
this.setState({ cards: newCards });`

instead of trying to mutate the state object directly.

Comment: ^^ that would also mutate the state object directly since you are using push. You should be using `concat` instead which returns a new array. Push also returns the length of the array so in your exmaple `newCards` would actually equal a number instead of the array.